# A horror movie about witch in the attic

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

A few years ago I saw a horror movie, but now I can't recall its title.

The movie was colored, released after 2000. Original language - English. Unfortunately, I do not remember any names of characters or actors. And I do not know the country. The movie tells about present days or near it.

This is a movie about a guy who rented a room in one old house. He was a student and he needed a quiet place to study. His room was on the second floor. There was one strange corner in the room - it was bent into the room by half a meter or so as if inside there was ventilation or something like that.

Next to his room was the room of a young woman with a newborn baby. On the first floor next to the stairs was the room of an old gray-haired man who looked a little crazy.

The guy quickly became acquainted with a neighbor woman when she needed help in her room (to nail the board to the wall or something like that). The woman was looking for work and she did not have a husband.

The old man never left his room on the first floor and only watched the protagonist through the half-open door as he descended the stairs.

After a while, strange things began to happen in the guy's room - he began to hear voices. At such moments the old man from the first floor loudly read the prayers and beat his forehead to the floor. The guy noticed that the sound comes from this strange corner in his room, and decided to pick open the wall. Inside, he found something like a shaft leading up. However, he did not go further into the wall.

Strange things began to happen more often and more intensively, so the guy cracked the wall so much that he could get inside. The shaft led to the attic, where there were many ritual magical stuff.

One day the guy managed to talk with the old man from the first floor. There were many Christian elements in his room. He said that the witch lives in the attic and that he once committed a great sin, so he has to live all his life in this house and pray without ceasing so that the witch does not get strength again. But with the appearance of the protagonist, she again began to act and, in his words, "she is going for you."

At the end of the movie,

> a woman from the next room asked the guy to take a look at her child while she was at the interview at a new job. The guy agreed, fall asleep, and the witch appeared, bewitched him. Here I do not exactly remember what happened, but the child was dead when the woman returned. She blamed the guy. The death of the child gave something to the witch, something like another prolongation of life.

The exact same thing happened to the old man from the first floor. This is why he stays in the house and constantly tries to stop the witch.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a TV episode, not a movie, What you probably saw was [Dreams in the Witch-House](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._P._Lovecraft%27s_Dreams_in_the_Witch-House):

> H. P. Lovecraft's Dreams in the Witch House is the second episode of the first season of Masters of Horror, directed by Stuart Gordon. It is adapted from the short story "The Dreams in the Witch House" by American horror author H. P. Lovecraft. It originally aired in North America on November 4, 2005.

Some of the plot:

> **University student Walter Gilman moves to a very cheap room in an old boarding house**. He hears shrill screaming and rushes to help his neighbor, Frances, to find that she was being chased by a large rat. He seeks assistance from the manager, but he refuses to help. One of the tenants, Masurewicz, asks Walter if the large rat had a human face. He becomes close with Frances the following week, and even lends her money to keep her in the boarding house.
>
> The old man advises Walter about a rat with a man's face and a witch that would be after him. He warns Walter that the house is evil, relating that he, like Walter, moved in at a young age in the same room that Walter is currently renting. **He stays in the house only to pray to stop her.**

The ending (Danny being the child):

> Frances, the manager, and the police finally open the door to find Walter covered in blood—with Danny's corpse in his lap. Walter is taken to a psych ward and is diagnosed with paranoid schizophrenia.